# Conservation of momentum vs newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

I saw this question from a book:

An empty sled is sliding on frictionless ice when Susan drops vertically from a tree down onto the sled. When she lands, does the sled speed up, slow down, or keep the same speed?

The speed will decrease because of the added mass of the system, according to the conservation of momentum.

However, I was wondering that the horizontal net force is still 0, so isn't acceleration still 0? How can the speed decrease?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Susan won't immediately acquire the sled's velocity. There will need to be a horizontal frictional force between the sled and Susan's backside after she lands on the seat in order to accelerate her to the speed of the sled. An equal and opposite force will decelerate the sled.

Since this won't happen instantly, if the sled is moving fast enough Susan will likely fall off the rear of the sled unless the seat has a back.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law for a system tells that the net external force is equal to the mass of the system times the acceleration of the cenetr of mass.
For the case described in the OP the horizontal force is zero and this means that the horizontal component of the velocity of the center of mass does not change. The horizontal velocities of the components change due to the internal forces but the center of mass keeps the same velocity.
If we label the parameters of the sled as $m_1$ and $v_1$ and the parameters of the falling object as $m_2$, the velocity of the center of mass before contact is (taking the time derivative of the position of the center of mass on the horizontal direction)
$$v_{CM}= \frac{m_1v_1}{m1+m2}$$
When they move together, the new velocity is given bu the conservation of momentum and it is $$v_{final}=\frac{m_1v_1}{m1+m2} $$ and as they move as one object, the center of mass moves with the same velocity, $v_{final}$.
It is clear that the velocity of the center of mass did not change, as required by the second law.
Both conservation of momentum and Newton's second law work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the combination of the sled, Susan and the Earth as an isolated system for which momentum is, by definition, conserved as follows:

1. The sled slows down losing its horizontal momentum. However, Susan gains an equal amount of horizontal momentum after landing on the sled so that the horizontal momentum of the combination of Susan and the sled is conserved.
2. Susan loses vertical momentum when she lands on the sled. But as the Earth (and sled) pull Susan down,  Susan pulls up on the Earth and sled giving them an equal and opposite amount of vertical momentum. Thus vertical momentum is also conserved.
3. With regard to the sled slowing down (decelerating), that is due to an internal force in the system, namely the horizontal  friction force between Susan and the sled keeping them together (as long as the maximum possible static friction force is not exceeded). It also causes Susan to accelerate forward. Since this force is internal to the system, it has no effect on the momentum of the system. If Susan should happen to slide off the sled, The total momentum of the system (Susan, sled, Earth) will still continue to be conserved.

Hope this helps.